# Don't understand runtime error

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

having a problem hard to understand. I have a ShinobiGrid view in a viewcontroller. 
Trying to center the grid at the middle of the grid (column) with

```
spreadSheet.SetContentOffset(new PointF(200, 0), true);
```

By doing that I get a runtime exception and I don't understand it (since I'm not a Objective-C programmer).
What's going on?

```
{MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  
Name:       NSRangeException Reason: *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: 
index 1 beyond bounds for empty array   at (wrapper managed-to-native)     
MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_PointF_bool 
(intptr,intptr,System.Drawing.PointF,bool)   at 
MonoTouch.UIKit.UIScrollView.SetContentOffset   
(PointF contentOffset, Boolean animated) [0x00027] in 
/Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIScrollView.g.cs:210    at 
Roombler.Gui.IPad.ViewControllers.RoomblerViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x0011c] in 
/Users/jonas/Documents/Roombler/BitBucket/Roombler.Gui/Roombler.Gui.IPad/ViewControllers/RoomblerViewController.cs:97    
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend  
(intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible () [0x00010] in 
/Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIWindow.g.cs:124    at 
Roombler.Gui.IPad.ViewControllers.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching 

(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) 
[0x00031] in
/Users/jonas/Documents/Roombler/BitBucket/Roombler.Gui/Roombler.Gui.IPad/ViewControllers/AppDelegate.cs:29    
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain 
(int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] 
args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in 
/Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38    at 
Roombler.Gui.IPad.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in 
/Users/jonas/Documents/Roombler/BitBucket/Roombler.Gui/Roombler.Gui.IPad/Main.cs:17 }
```

Comment: Post more of your code, it doesn't seem like the error matches the code you posted.  It is the equivalent of an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, but you are not using an array here.

Answer (score 0):

The support team at ShinobiControll helped me out.

"The grid doesn't know how big it is at that point. You could put

spreadSheet.Reload();

in before the SetContentOffset"

That did the trick!